# Double-escaped label in SelectOneMenu in PrimeFaces 12

Tags: primefaces, escaping, selectonemenu

In PrimeFaces’ *SelectOneMenu*, I use options (often placeholders) like `<please select>`, loaded from controller via *f:selectItems* and escaped automatically by the *SelectOneMenu* component. After updating PrimeFaces 11 to version 12, the component started to double-escape the characters `<`, `>`, `&` in its label, while the option list is still rendered as expected. (When I click `<please select>`, the label shows `&lt;please select&gt;`.)

I tried all combinations of these settings:

- view: *f:selectItems.itemLabelEscaped* = `"true"`/`"false"`
- controller: *SelectItem.escape* = `"true"`/`"false"`
- controller: *SelectItem.label* is/isn’t escaped manually

The attribute *itemLabelEscaped* has no effect. Other combinations work as follows:

| No. | SelectItem.escape | SelectItem.label | Option in dropdown | Shown label in PF 11 | Shown label in PF 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | false | `< <i>italics</i>` | < *italics* | italics | italics |
| 2 | false | `&lt; &lt;i&gt;italics&lt;/i&gt;` | < <i>italics</i> | < *italics* | < <i>italics</i> |
| 3 | true | `< <i>italics</i>` | < <i>italics</i> | < <i>italics</i> | &lt; &lt;i&gt;italics&lt;/i&gt; |
| 4 | true | `&lt; &lt;i&gt;italics&lt;/i&gt;` | &lt; &lt;i&gt;italics&lt;/i&gt; | &lt; &lt;i&gt;italics&lt;/i&gt; | *(even more escaped)* |

In PrimeFaces 11, I used the setting No. 3, and the label was the same as the option in dropdown. After the update, the label gets broken and the only working setting seems to be No. 2, but I don’t want to update all occurrences of *selectItems* unless necessary.

As I did not find any relevant info in PrimeFaces’ release notes, I would consider it a bug, but I wonder nobody has reported it yet, so I’m not sure: **is it a bug, or a feature?** [This old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44135691/pselectonemenu-and-unescaped-selectitem-label) seems to be relevant, but how come it worked in PrimeFaces 11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known and fixed issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/9336). Until PrimeFaces 13 is released, you can [MonkeyPatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594082/monkeypatching-primefaces-widgets-extend-override) the [workaround](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/9336#issuecomment-1289252686).

Comment: Great, I have been looking for some report for several days. However, the _MonkeyPatch_ is problematic. It truly fixes the handling of `<>&` which I asked for, but at the same time – regardless of any settings – it removes all characters after the first double quote, so that `some "quoted" value` becomes `some`. For this reason, I’m afraid the patch is not applicable in my case, but at least I know it’s a bug.

Comment: @JosefPlch it worked incorrectly in PF11 as well it needs to be escaped and HTML needs to be handled.  if you read starting here we even have integration tests for this and its because it has to be able to render HTML: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/9336#issuecomment-1294057217

Comment: @JasperdeVries OK, I reported the problem and the proposed solution [at GitHub](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/9336#issuecomment-1373500919). After the fix, the settings No. 2 and 3 listed above behave the same way.

Answer (score 2):

OK it should be fixed for good in PF 13.0 and this MonkeyPatch should solve all your current issues.

```js
if (PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu) {
    PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu.prototype.renderSelectItem = function(item, isGrouped) {
        var content = "";
        var $item = $(item);
        var label;
        var title = $item.data("title");
        var escape = $item.data("escape");
        var cssClass;

        if (item.tagName === "OPTGROUP") {
            label = $item.attr("label");
            if (escape) {
                label = $("<div>").text(label).html();
            }
            cssClass = "ui-selectonemenu-item-group ui-corner-all";
        } else { //OPTION
            if (escape) {
                label = $item.html();
                if ($item.text() === "&nbsp;") {
                    label = $item.text();
                }
            } else {
                label = $item.text();
            }
            
            cssClass = "ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all";
            if (isGrouped) {
                cssClass += " ui-selectonemenu-item-group-children";
            }
        }

        var dataLabel = escape ? label.replaceAll('"', '&quot;') : this.escapeHTMLIfNecessary(label);

        if ($item.data("noselection-option")) {
            cssClass += " ui-noselection-option";
        }

        content += '<li class="' + cssClass + '" tabindex="-1" role="option"';
        if (title) {
            content += ' title="' + title + '"';
        }
        if ($item.is(':disabled')) {
            content += ' disabled';
        }
        content += ' data-label="' + dataLabel + '"';
        content += '>';
        content += label;
        content += '</li>';

        if (item.tagName === "OPTGROUP") {
            content += this.renderSelectItems($item, true);
        }

        return content;
    };

    PrimeFaces.widget.SelectOneMenu.prototype.escapeHTMLIfNecessary = function(value) {
            return String(value).replace(/[<>"'`=\/]/g, function(s) {
                return PrimeFaces.entityMap[s];
            });
     };
}
```

Comment: This makes the label in PrimeFaces 12 work the same way as it did in version 11. The question is: would’t it be better to leave the label unchanged and keep `< <i>italics</i>` for both No. 2 and 3? This is the behaviour of [my fix](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/9336#issuecomment-1373500919). It is up to the individual developer to decide which solution is better.

Comment: I answered in the PF ticket.  Looks like yours misses one of your use cases.